# Update a single field when saving an entity

Tags: 7, entities, views

**Question:** How do I update a single field of an entity? For example, lets say I have a user and want to update field_my_field. How do I just update that without using user_save?

**My Specific Problem:** 
I have a a bunch of user fields defined, and am trying to optimize the performance of my site. I am using **views_bulk_operations**, and my code is timing out (maximum execution time) because I am repeatedly calling user_save, and it's an expensive operation.

I am only updating a single field, and would like to optimize this code. Rather than calling user_save, which is taking 500ms to run, I'd like to update the field directly.

I attempted to use field_attach_update(), and that works a little better, but that's also updating all the fields. Is there any specific way just to update or save a specific field for an entity?

I'm not interested in batch operations, or anything at the moment -- I know how to do that, and can convert this into a batch so I don't run into execution timeouts. I just want to know how to save a single field for an entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try with [field_sql_storage_field_storage_write](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!field_sql_storage!field_sql_storage.module/function/field_sql_storage_field_storage_write/7).

See this [blog post with an example](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-update-and-insert-only-specific-fields-your-entity):

```
//Get the id of your field
$name = 'name_of_your_field';
$info = field_info_field($field_name);
$fields = array(info['id']); 

//Execute the storage function
field_sql_storage_field_storage_write('model', $entity, 'update', $fields);
```

Comment: This worked for the most part, thanks. I am running into some caching issues, not sure whether it's with memcache, drupal or APC, but it's out of scope of this question.

Comment: For future reference, the problem we are facing was with entitycache. Our entity was being cached, and it was displaying the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 create new table for each field, there is no entry in this table if value is not available for this field. To save value in this field further use **field_attach_update** instead node_load.`

```
$field = new stdClass();
$field->type = 'story_cover'; // content type name
$field->nid = $node->nid; // node id
$field->field_number_of_pages[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'YOUR_VALUE'; // field name
field_attach_update('node', $field);
```

Comment: See also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/64838/8027

Answer (score -1):

You have to first load the logged in user and then use entity module function entity_metadata_wrapper to update the user field, but be pretty sure to enable the entity module.

```
            $account = user_load_by_name($uname);
    $user = user_load($account->uid);
    $obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
    $obj->{field_machine_name}['und']['0']['value'] ="your value" ;
    $obj->save();
```