# How to use field_attach_update for users

Tags: users

I have read this post [fast saving single field value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64833/fast-saving-single-field-value/64838#64838) about how to use field_attach_update to save nodes without the overhead of node_save().

I would like to use this for users (which it should work for, as per https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7) . However, I'm not sure how to apply the examples to users.

Currently, this is my code:

```
if (isset($uid)) {
    $user = user_load($uid);
    $user_og_groups = $user->og_user_node[LANGUAGE_NONE];
    $user_committee_positions = $user->field_committee_position_serno[LANGUAGE_NONE];
    $user_data = my_module_import_user($cust_info, $cust_attributes, $drupal_countries, $employers);
    $user = user_save($user, $user_data);
  }
```

The $user_data variable is an array of data, which is what user_save expects (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7). `user_save()` doesn't work exactly the same as `node_save()` and doesn't accept a user object.

How then can I use field_attach_update to programmatically update users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your function my_module_import_user return right data? I think user_save() work fine. You can try

```
if (isset($uid)) {
  $account = user_load($uid);
  $edit = array();
  $edit['field_FIELD_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'Field Value';
  // add more data
  user_save($account, $edit);
}
```

if you want use **field_attach_update**

```
if (isset($uid)) {
  $account = user_load($uid);
  $account->field_FIELD_NAME[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'Field Value';
  // add more data
  field_attach_update('user', $account);
}
```

And my way, i often use [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers)

```
if (isset($uid)) {
  $account = user_load($uid);
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account);
  //Set data of field
  $wrapper->field_FIELD_NAME->set('Field Value');
  // set more data here
  $wrapper->save();
}
```