# How to insert field value programmatically after node is created?

Tags: nodes, entities

Let's say user creates a `node` of `article` type.There is a `field` called `my_field` which can be added `multiple` times to that `node`.If user **creates** or **edits** the `node` leaving `my_field` blank, a default value something like **NA** should be created in database and should be visible inside the `my_field` when user **edits**  `node` next time.

**Tried so far:**

Inside page.tpl.php

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);

  foreach ($nids as $nid) {

    $node = node_load($nid);

   if(empty($node->field_my_field))
   {
     $field_language = field_language('node', $node, 'field_my_field');
     $node->field_my_field['LANGUAGE_NONE'][0]['value'] = 'NA';

      field_attach_insert('node', $node);
   }
  }
 }
```

**Note:** I don't want to create default value inside **field settings** as `my_field` can be added multiple times which can go upto more than 20.

I am using drupal `7.41`.

Comment: You really should not be doing this in `page.tpl.php`. This code scans all your nodes on every page load, which is a huge performance loss. You should do this in a custom module implementing [`hook_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and [`hook_node_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7). Act only after saving or editing a node.

Comment: I tried the same with above hooks,field value didn't go to databse.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is due to your `field_attach_insert()`. Usually one should save the entire node using `node_save()`. 
However it is a lot easier if you install the [entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module and utilize its [Entity Metadata Wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers).

And I'd really recommend creating a custom module. You will need something similar to this:

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    mymodule_update_empty_value($node);
  }
}

function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'article') {
    mymodule_update_empty_value($node);
  }
}

function mymodule_update_empty_value($node) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  // No value? 
  if  (empty($wrapper->field_myfield->value())) {
    $wrapper->field_myfield->set('NA');
    $wrapper->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: how abt if it is for specific bundle say `article`?

Comment: Added the condition in the example, the same applies to `status`.

Comment: showing error                                                                                                                                 EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (line 122 of /var/www/drupal3.com/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Comment: is the field a textfield?

Comment: textarea with rows

Comment: Obtain a value of a known node with `entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid)->field_myfield->value();` and see how it is structured (there might be another layer). Also take a look at the bottom of the linked entity metadata wrapper page. There are some dubuggin functions there as well.
The body field (which is similar to what you might need can be set with `$wrapper->body->set(array('value' => "<b>Der zweite Text.</b>"));`

Comment: `textfield` and `long text` are not supporting `set` method.How to set values for those types,any clue?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that, but you can either use the field array `$node->field_my_field['LANGUAGE_NONE'][0]['value'] = 'NA';` and `node_save()`. Or take a look here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64833/fast-saving-single-field-value

Comment: above link is ok if you want to update existing field value,but problem is for newly created node